# The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System'

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, linq, visual-studio-2015

When I want to use button to write code in C# it doesn't go to the ".cs" file to write C# code. When I check the project source, I found this error:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
```

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error  CS0234  The type or
> namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are
> you missing an assembly reference?)   Golestani C:\Users\javad\Documents\Golestani\Login.aspx.cs 3

[image]

Comment: What Do You Mean??

Comment: Right click your project -> Add Reference -> select Framework tab -> select System.Core

Comment: Go to project  -> References -> Add Reference ->  -> Assemblies -> Search for "System.Xml.Linq" and check it.

Answer (score 71):

I had an issue with System.Linq not being recognized. 
The way I solved it was to change the targeted framework of my website from 4.0 to to 3.5 and then switch back to the original targeted framework (in my case 4.0)

1. Hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> or **right click at the project level and select Property Pages** in Visual Studio. (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or **right click at the project level and select Properties** in VS2017.)
2. Change the Target Framework from **.Net Framework 4** to **.Net Framework 3.5**
3. Confirm with **OK**
4. Repeat this process in reverse so, again hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>
5. Change it back from **.Net Framework 3.5** to **.Net Framework 4**

Hope this helps

Comment: If Shift+F4 doesn't work, just right click at the project level and select "Property Pages"

Comment: That did work for me after hours of research. Thanks

Comment: VS is nice when it works, but its some ungodly Frankenstein collection of stuff and things go to hell frequently and are a nightmare figure out.  It's frustrating when you decide to reinstall windows just to get VS to work again.  Teach me to try to use it for R and Python and still expect C# to work too.

Comment: This action may change the content of web.config, suggest to check what content is modify after change, to ensure that no function is thus disabled.

Comment: In my case (*changing from Framework 2.0 to Framework 3.5*) fixed the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 31):

Try to Unload and then reload the concerned project. That will do it.

Comment: yup, just closing and reopening VS2017 did it for me. Happens often for various issues.

Comment: This worked for me in VS 2022

Answer (score 4):

Put this piece of code in the Configuration file (**Web.config**) and test it.

```
<compilation debug="false">
<assemblies>
<add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
<add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
<add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
<add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
<add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
</assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Comment: I had success with this change, although I only needed to do System.Core.  And for those who haven't memorized the the Web.config XML schema, the <compilation> element goes under <system.web>.  @Hamed, I urge you to change your answer to include <system.web> and to fix the syntax highlighting.

Comment: Worked on Windows 2008 R2 for an age old intranet website. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio 2015 References -> Add Reference -> Assemblies -> select System.Data.Linq

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. Maybe targetFramework="4.0" will work. Worked for me.

```html
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0">
<assemblies>
<add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
<add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
<add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
</assemblies>
</compilation>
```